# Document event listener not working consistently on mobile

Tags: javascript, event-handling, polymer, dom-events

**Functionality trying to achieve** - A drop down menu when an icon is clicked. Drop down to disappear when clicked/tapped on the button or anywhere else in the screen.

**Method chosen** -

*For button interactions:* Add an event listener to the button and toggle the drop down height and add a CSS height transition. --> Works well across both mobile and desktop.

*For window interactions:* Add an overall click and tap listener to the document when the dropdown is on and then remove the listeners when the dropdown disappears. --> Works well on desktop, but is inconsistent on mobile devices.

**What is the inconsistency?**

The tap at random locations of the document are registered on 3rd or 4th or 5th taps and are very inconsistent. This can be checked through opening the demo page on mobile chrome or mobile simulator on desktop Chrome dev tab as well.

**Demo page:** http://52.74.151.136:8080/custom_components/folder-card/demo.html

**Code used:** The Javascript code inside the Polymer call is as below.

```
toggleActionPane: function() {
    console.dir(this.$.actionpane);
    this.tapHandler = this.handleMyTap.bind(this);
     if (this.$.actionpane.classList.contains("hidden")) {
        this.$.actionpane.classList.remove("hidden");
        this.$.actionpane.classList.add("dropped");
        document.addEventListener('click', this.tapHandler);
        document.addEventListener('down', this.tapHandler);
    } else {
        this.$.actionpane.classList.remove("dropped");
        this.$.actionpane.classList.add("hidden");
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.tapHandler);
        document.removeEventListener('down', this.tapHandler);          
    }
},
handleMyTap: function(e) {
    console.log("Inside the document tap function");
    if (this.$.actionpane.classList.contains("dropped")) {
        this.$.actionpane.classList.remove("dropped");
        this.$.actionpane.classList.add("hidden");
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.tapHandler);
        document.removeEventListener('down', this.tapHandler);  
    }
}
```

**Solution required:**

1. Underlying problem with the code or implementation
2. Ways to get around the issue I am facing

Comment: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-menu

Comment: I will replace the paper-element with paper-menu once the event listeners are working correctly. But before that, I need to understand the underlying problem with the inconsistent behavior.